# Json jackson mapping ask

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

How can I map the following json payload to a more friendly dictionary like look up?  The data I get back is coming back as generic key values in a list. But I want to be able to access everything as a dictionary lookup by the key instead of storing everything as a list.

```
[
   {
      "key":"value1",
      "values":[
         10.5
      ]
   },
   {
      "key":"value2",
      "values":[
         20.5
      ]
   }
   o o o more values here... o o o
]
```

This is what I have for object to map but I want to map by key to automatically building a hashmap or dictionary withough having to iterate thought the list.

```
class keyValPairObject {
    private String key;
    private List<?> values;
}

class mainMapper {
    List<keyValPairObject> theKeyValPairValues;
}
```

I'd like to store it in an object where I can access it like:

```
 theKeyValPairValues["values1"].values;
```

Comment: So why don't you just use a HashMap object to begin with?  Then you can set each key to a String and each value to a List.  The syntax will be a little different than what you stated: map.get("values1");  That will return the list of values for the key "values1".

Comment: How could I map it to the hashmap object automatically per Jackson or would it be a manual process iterating each json list then building a hashmap?

Comment: @UpAllNight: Thx for the reply, so would I have to manually create the hashmap or would jackson map it automatically for me?  Not sure how I could set this up.

Comment: I put some code in the answers for you.  Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should use "Tree Models", so that:

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonSource);
```

and then you can traverse values using "get()" and "path()" methods. `path()` is nice since you can skip any null checks (if a node does not exist, a virtual "missing" node is included, so you can freely chain calls).

That way you would do like:

```
int value = rootNode.path(0).path("value").path(0).asIntValue();
```

to get that `10.5` value from your structure.

Bit more info can be found from [this entry](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/08/entry_460.html) and from "[Tree Model](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind)" of databind project's readme.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I hope this helps you.  Here is some code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public String hashmapToJson() {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String result = "";

    HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    String key1 = "values1";
    String key2 = "values2";
    String key3 = "values3";

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        list1.add("Element" + i);
        list2.add("Element" + i);
        list3.add("Element" + i);
    }

    map.put(key1, list1);
    map.put(key2, list2);
    map.put(key3, list3);

    try {
        result = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;

}
```

This will return:

```
{
 "values1":["Element0","Element1","Element2"],
 "values2":["Element0","Element1","Element2"],
 "values3":["Element0","Element1","Element2"]
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?